# Jenkinsfile - how to pass build argument to docker

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile

As per this [link](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) we can pass image name & dockerfile location to build an image in following way

```
docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "-f ${dockerfile} ./dockerfiles")
```

I want to pass proxy settings to build command, Is there any way to pass it, similar to how we can pass in simple docker command.

```
docker build -t my-image --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.0.1:3128 ./dockerfiles
```

Comment: That should work the way you are doing it.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, it works when I build it on cmd manually but not able to pass proxy settings while building image from Jenkinsfile.

Comment: So `docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.0.1:3128 -f ${dockerfile} ./dockerfiles")` does not work?

Comment: No, it does not work. it throws error below.```org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 48: Method calls on objects not allowed outside "script" blocks. @ line 48, column 8.
          docker.build("$registry/errorhandler:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", "HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.0.1:3128 -f Dockerfile ./errorhandler")```

Comment: This kind of sounds like a bug with the Docker plugin.

Answer (score 14):

This works for me:

```
def image = docker.build("myregistry.io/firstkey/secondkey/image:2.2.0-$BUILD_NUMBER", "--build-arg http_proxy=http://www-proxy.mycompany.com:80 --build-arg https_proxy=http://www-proxy.mycompay.com:80 --network host -f Dockerfile .")
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for this method? I struggle to navigate the Jenkins.io docs...

Comment: @JesusIniesta https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals

Answer (score 8):

All you need to add `.` in the second argument.

`docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "--build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.0.1:3128 .")`

Answer (score 3):

```
docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "--build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://192.168.0.1:3128", "-f ${dockerfile} ./dockerfiles")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it like this, with giving space in between as a string

`docker.build "my-image:${env.BUILD_ID} -f ${dockerfile} ./dockerfiles"`

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of new lines and spaces in build args when you passing them to docker.build().

Perform trim() on them before passing to the docker.build()

[Pass to docker.build several --build-arg arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69122042/pass-to-docker-build-several-build-arg-arguments/69127696#69127696)