# Pass to docker.build several --build-arg arguments

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to pass two build arguments in Jenkinsfile.

Works with single --build-arg:

```
app = docker.build("myimg:${Version}", "--build-arg VERSION=${Version} --no-cache ."
```

But doesn't work with several:

```
app = docker.build("myimg:${Version}", "--build-arg VERSION=${Version} --build-arg  CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN=${CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN} --no-cache ."
```

Output Error: `"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.`

How can I pass two or more build arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in number of build-args but with CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN variable.

The CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN variable probably contained new lines.

Therefore this line fixed the issue:

```
CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN = CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN.trim()
```

Answer (score 3):

Feels like it is something Jenkins expect from you.

Jenkins doc says

> It is possible to pass other arguments to docker build by adding them
> to the second argument of the build() method. When passing arguments
> this way, the last value in the that string must be the path to the
> docker file and should end with the folder to use as the build
> context)

you should try adding `-f ${dockerfile}` right before context `.`
so it looks like this

`app = docker.build("myimg:${Version}", "--build-arg VERSION=${Version} --build-arg  CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN=${CODEARTIFACT_TOKEN} --no-cache -f Dockerfile ."`

assuming your Dockerfile is in current folder.

here is doc:

1. List item

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/